# onsen tabbar is not defined / access tabbar object which is inside navigator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to access the tabbar object "appTabbar" which is inside an ons-page. This page is managed by the ons-navigator "appNavigator".

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-tabbar var="appTabbar" ng-controller="routingCtrl">
       ....
    </ons-tabbar>
</ons-page>
```

The navigator is placed inside index.html

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="appNavigator" ng-controller="routingCtrl">
       ...
</ons-navigator>
```

If i assign "routingCtrl" as their controller it should be possible to catch occuring events of "appTabbar" and "appNavigator".

```
.controller('routingCtrl', function ($scope) {

      ons.ready(function () {

          appNavigator.on('prepop', function (event) {
              console.log("pop");
          });

          appTabbar.on('prechange', function (event) {
              console.log("prechange");
          });
      });
  });
```

"routingCtrl" recognises events of appNavigator without a problem, but in case of "appTabbar" when loading the ons-page Chrome throws:

Uncaught ReferenceError: appTabbar is not defined

How do i get access to "appTabbar", which is loaded dynamically after ons.ready? Is it only possible to access objects of elements, which exist right from the beginnung (i already tested moving "appTabbar" to index.html, it works)?

Backgroundinfo: Everytime a view changes (including changing tabs) i want to check if the user is logged in. In the current situation i only know if something happens with "appNavigator".

Comment: If the tabbar hasn't been loaded the appTabbar object will not exist so you cannot use it. There are some attributes to handle events that may help you (`ons-prechange`): http://onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html#attributes
They also exist for Navigator and other elements.

Comment: Thats what i wanted :) Is it possible to pass the event object via ons-prechange? lets say i call an angularjs function and pass the event object to it. in the function i stop the current push, because user is not logged in

Comment: Yes, you can pass the event object. Here there is an example: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/aOqLZW

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. See detailed Informations in the comments below my question.